# Laggy typing and cursor jumps with TextField?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, core-data

My app uses TextFields everywhere to modify CoreData entities' String attributes. They work very poorly - typing a space or getting an auto correct event seems to make the cursor jump to the end of the window. Keystrokes are missed and the whole experience is laggy. TextEditors, on the other hand, work fine. The behavior doesn't appear on the simulator, only on (multiple) real devices.

What am I doing wrong here? Am I using TextFields wrong?

[image]

Code is below, it's basically the starter Xcode app with a "text: String?" attribute added to the "item" CoreData entity.

```
struct Detail: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var item: Item
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Form {
                Section(content: {
                    TextField("Title", text: $item.text ?? "")
                }, header: {
                    Text("TextField")
                })
                
                Section(content: {
                    TextEditor(text: $item.text ?? "")
                }, header: {
                    Text("TextEditor")
                })
            }
            
        }
    }
}

// Optional binding used
func ??<T>(lhs: Binding<Optional<T>>, rhs: T) -> Binding<T> {
    Binding(
        get: { lhs.wrappedValue ?? rhs },
        set: { lhs.wrappedValue = $0 }
    )
}
```

## Update:

I ended up just putting the TextFields into a subview and then writing their value back to the NSManagedObject via a binding every time the value changes.

I have no idea why, but this fixes the problem for me.

```
struct CustomTextField: View {
    
    @Binding var string: String?
    @State var localString: String
    let prompt: String
    
    init(string: Binding<String?>, prompt: String) {
        
        _string = string
        _localString = State(initialValue: string.wrappedValue ?? "")
        self.prompt = prompt
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField(prompt, text: $localString, axis: .vertical)
            .onChange(of: localString, perform: { _ in
                string = localString
            })
    }
}
```

Comment: How often do you save the changes to the database? Maybe you want to make sure only do so `.onSubmit`

Answer (score 0):

Example of using onSubmit, which does not cause CoreData to save the data on every input by the keyboard.

```
struct Detail: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var item: Item
    @State var text: String = "" // for starting with an empty textfield
// Alternative if you want the data from item:
    // @State var text: String = item.text.wrappedValue // This only works if text is a binding.
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Form {
                Section(content: {
                    TextField("Title", text: $text)
                        .onSubmit {
                            item.text = self.text
                        }
                }, header: {
                    Text("TextField")
                })
                
                Section(content: {
                    TextEditor(text: $text)
                        .onSubmit {
                            item.text = self.text
                        }
                }, header: {
                    Text("TextEditor")
                })
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

If that does not help, it would be nice to know how Item looks like.

Comment: It would be good if, instead of just posting code with no explanation, you described why this code would work better than the code in the question. What problems in the original code are fixed in your code?

Comment: Using .onSubmit() doesn't work well from a UX perspective because if a user taps another TextField on the screen, the changes to the first TextField are lost as focus is transferred.

Comment: @Christian you are right that does not make sense from UX perspective. On your update you use onDisappear which makes much more sense, but i would recommend not using an optional binding. I am still not sure if I understand correctly what you want to achive. Could you clerify this more?

Comment: Item is a CoreData NSManagedObject so it's String attributes have to be optional.

My goal is for a user to be able to type easily and for every keystroke to be written to the Item.Text: String? property. It shouldn't be a tough ask for SwiftUI, it's how most people do it. I'm just not sure why it's acting so buggy.

Comment: I have had a similar issue where I manipulated the input when certain characters typed. This caused also a jump of the cursor. I could not determine the reason for this, but my guess that swiftui causes this issue in the background. I then switched to UIKit and used UIViewRepresentable. In your case it is maybe due to the fact that you use one Binding for two input sources and those updates in the background cause the issue. Did you try using only one TF and animate the input to a Text? You could use the .onChange method for that.

Comment: Can you guard let before you instantiate the struct, so that you do not inject an optional?